# How can I add some lines from x0 to x1 and y0 to y1 to my animated Plotly scatter plot in python?

Tags: python, animation, plotly

I have this code produced in Python (using plotly) which produces an animated scatter plot of a specfic NFL play using tracking data:

```
fig = px.scatter(data,  x = "x", y = "y", hover_name="displayName",
          color="team", animation_frame = "frameId", animation_group = "displayName",
          range_y = [-10, 60])

fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]['frame']['duration'] = 80
```

And I would like to add lines that go from [x0, y0] to [x1, y1] and would like to know how I would be able to do that?

Thanks

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70166633/draw-line-in-plotly-between-2-points) may help you, the question seems similar.

Comment: are you saying you want like a trail line?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean by that but I just want a straight line that goes from A to B

Comment: ok. but regardless, you need to share some sample data. Can't do much if you don't share what your data looks like.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to use any data I just want to draw a line between two arbitrary points. So say I have point A at [1, 2] and point B at [3,4], how can I draw a line linking them?

Comment: Oh ok. So you mean to "line" out a football field. You need to be a little more clearer in your posts/questions. You also should include minimal amount of code to reproduce what you are trying to accomplish, including your imports and what not. So yes, since your code above does call into use the `data` dataframe, you should be including that here in the post.